# Insert new data into collection mongodb php

Tags: php, database, mongodb

after searching on internet everywhere I still can't figure it out how to insert new data in my database collection without deleting the existing data. The code written till now is the following:

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => true]);
$bulk->delete([]);
$bulk -> insert(['accessToken'=>'PQRST','ID'=>'789']);
$writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
        $connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        try {
            $result = $connection->executeBulkWrite('db.collection', $bulk,$writeConcern);
        } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException $e) {
            $result = $e->getWriteResult();
            if ($writeConcernError = $result->getWriteConcernError()) {
                printf("%s (%d): %s\n",
                $writeConcernError->getMessage(),
                $writeConcernError->getCode(),
                var_export($writeConcernError->getInfo(), true)
                ); 
            }

            // Check if any write operations did not complete at all
            foreach ($result->getWriteErrors() as $writeError) {
                printf("Operation#%d: %s (%d)\n",
                $writeError->getIndex(),
                $writeError->getMessage(),
                $writeError->getCode()
                );
            }
        } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
            printf("Other error: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
            exit;
        }
```

Hope that you can help me. Thanks